# MS Fakes, passing parameter into constructor

Tags: c#, microsoft-fakes, shim

I have the following concrete class

```
public class Service
{
    private IRepository _rep;

    public Service(IRepository rep)
    {
        _rep() = rep;
    }

    public Boolean Foo(Int32 param1)
    {
        _rep.Foo(param1);
    }

    public void Bar()
    {
        _rep.Bar();
    }
}
```

I have created the following shim for it.

```
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        ShimService shimService = new ShimService()
        {
            FooInt32 = (param1) => { return true; },
        };
    }
```

I want foo to always return true. This works.

I want Bar to operate normally. This doesn't work.

When I debug _rep is null so I believe I need to pass this an IRepository into the Shims constructor but I can't work out how to do it.

Comment: Your service class will not compile.  What are the return types of Foo and Bar?

Comment: Post amended,return typs for Foo is Boolean, Bar doesn't have one.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. You have to create an instance of the Service you want to Shim which includes the injection of IRepository and pass that that service into the Shim.....so

```
            IRepository rep = new Repository();
            Service service = new Service(rep);
            ShimSignOffService shimService = new ShimSignOffService(service)
            {
                IsBookmarkProcessedInt32 = (bookmarkId) => { return true; },

            };
```